# safe area includes notch?

Tags: swiftui, uikit, storyboard

I'm creating a launch screen by storyboard for a swiftui app. When I rotate the iPhone 14 to landscape, the safe area has insets on vertical, without any inset on horizontal(shown as the image below). IMO, the safe area should have inset on leading, trailing and bottom edge in this case. Do I miss anything?

[image]

Comment: Appears to be a bug with Xcode 14's Storyboard / Interface Builder

Comment: @DonMag Thank you for reply! I ran the code on an iPhone 14 simulator. The launch screen image overlapped the notch which indicates the issue will happen on a simulator in runtime. I have no real iPhone 14 device for now. I wonder whether the problem will happen or not on a device.

Comment: This is either a "bug" with iOS 16+ -- or, it is by design. I haven't found any documentation on it either way, other than similar posts. Also haven't seen any way to get around it.

Comment: @DonMag Thanks! Hope not having to wait too long.

Comment: As a side note... I've noticed fewer and fewer apps (at least, the apps I have) that use anything other than a small-ish logo on the LaunchScreen. Most are just blank. *In general*, we want to get to the first app screen as quickly as possible, so whatever is on the LaunchScreen is somewhat inconsequential. What are you designing on your LaunchScreen that you need to be concerned with the safe area?

Comment: @DonMag My app has a background color. Therefore, I prepare a launch screen with the same background color for visual consistency. It's good for portrait case. As for a "notch" device in landscape status, the background color will fill the whole screen during launch phase, while it then shrinks into the real safe area after launch phase. But I want the background color area to stay still without the shrunk effect. That's why I'm concerned with the safe area range.